# Converting UTC to EST - Snowflake !! Remove Z and T from the date

Tags: sql, datetime, type-conversion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to export this file to excel but it has those Z and T in the time stamp. How can i remove it? I did try to cast or use to_date but that didn't work. **This gives me CallBgn or CallEnd as "2022-08-29T09:57:18.297Z". I want it to be "2022-08-29 09:57:18.297"**

```
SELECT distinct      top 100  
                    b.ID as ID
                    ,convert_timezone('UTC','America/New_York',b.start_datetime_utc::timestamp) as CallBgn
                    ,convert_timezone('UTC','America/New_York',b.end_datetime_utc::timestamp)   as CallEnd
                    ,a.PNumber
From                pd_presentation.cus.cus_iss as a
left join           PD_PRESENTATION.CUS.CALL as b
on                  a.p_hk = b.p_hk
where               b.start_datetime_utc between '2022-08-28 00:00:00.000' AND '2022-09-17 23:59:59.997'
and                 a.p <> 'NOT GIVEN'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
substr(to_varchar(a.CallBgn1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),1,23)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is just a matter of presentation, so:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIMESTAMP_NTZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF';
```

Answer (score -1):

Not certain what version of SQL you are using, but I would suggest substring manipulation to cut off the unneeded character.  I would also suggest using the Excel functions rather than the SQL functions is more expedient if your data set is relatively small.

Mariadb convert_tz function does not append Z or T as you mention.

```
MariaDB [locks]> select now(),convert_tz(now(),'+00:00','+06:00');
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
| now()               | convert_tz(now(),'+00:00','+06:00') |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
| 2022-09-22 16:17:09 | 2022-09-22 22:17:09                 |
+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The following chops the seconds off the current time using either substr or left functions:

```
MariaDB [locks]> select now(),substr(now(),1,16), left(now(),16);;
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
| now()               | substr(now(),1,16)   | left(now(),16)   |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 2022-09-22 16:11:14 | 2022-09-22 16:11 | 2022-09-22 16:11 |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```